# how to implement virtual filesystem with PHP and Flex?

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, virtualfilesystem

I am creating an EDM (Electronic document Management) system which will use Flex for front-end , PHP at server side  and Mysql as database . Since its an EDM a single file will have many versions old copies will be stored hence one to one files mapping is not a choice . Wondering whats the best way to do so . Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the version control system of your choice (Subversion, Git, ...) for file versioning and creating a (or using an existing) PHP wrapper for your workflow?

Comment: good idea but our project is not that big also back-end should be in pure PHP .